# Get attachment meta (I need attachment ID, unsure how to find it)

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, post-meta

I've got the following example code, which creates a custom field and adds to the attachment meta:

```
function be_attachment_field_credit( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $form_fields['be-photographer-name'] = array(
        'label' => 'Photographer Name',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_photographer_name', true ),
        'helps' => 'If provided, photo credit will be displayed',
    );

    $form_fields['be-photographer-url'] = array(
        'label' => 'Photographer URL',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_photographer_url', true ),
        'helps' => 'Add Photographer URL',
    );

    return $form_fields;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'be_attachment_field_credit', 10, 2 );


function be_attachment_field_credit_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if( isset( $attachment['be-photographer-name'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'be_photographer_name', $attachment['be-photographer-name'] );

    if( isset( $attachment['be-photographer-url'] ) )
update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'be_photographer_url', esc_url( $attachment['be-photographer-url'] ) );

    return $post;
}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'be_attachment_field_credit_save', 10, 2 );
```

I've tried calling `var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID));`, but I assume that meta is somewhere else, as whatever input is not there.

[According to the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image), I can call:

`wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $unfiltered );`.

However, I have no idea how to get the `$attachment_id`.

My eventual goal is to add this meta data to the Advanced Custom Fields Gallery plugin, which adds the attachment meta to the post meta (I believe) — but that's down the road.

Comment: Where are you trying to get the attachement ID? The attachement ID is not meta data.

Comment: I'm trying to get whatever data has been submitted in the above code, and then add it to the post meta. So I can retrieve it like so: `get_post_meta($post->ID)`

Answer (score 1):

"Attachments" aren't meta data. That is why you can't retrieve them with `get_post_meta()`. "Attachments" are a post type that is attached to the parent post. You need to [pull the attachment posts that have you post set as parent](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children), and then use those `ID`s to get the attachment meta.

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type'   => 'attachment', 
    'numberposts' => -1 
);
$children = get_children($args);

foreach ($children as $c) {
  $att = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $c->ID, $unfiltered );
  var_dump($att);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the post meta you're saving is being attached to a post of type `attachment`, so in this case **`$post->ID` is the attachment ID.**